# Lefschetz hyperplane theorem through Morse Theory in G-H p158

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, morse-theory, holomorphic-bundles

I am reading the Morse theoretic proof of the Lefschetz Hyperplane theorem in Griffiths-Harris and I am missing a transition. They claim that since the matrix
$$\dfrac{1}{4}\left(\left(\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}+\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial y_i \partial y_j}\right) + i\left(\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i \partial y_j}-\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x_j\partial y_i}\right)\right)\log||s||^2$$

has $n$ negative eigenvalues, so does the Hessian
$$H(\varphi)= \begin{pmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i\partial x_j} & \dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i \partial y_j}\\
\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x_j\partial y_i} & \dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial y_i \partial y_j}
\end{pmatrix}\log ||s||^2$$
(there can be a permutation between the top right and bottom left corners).

I dont really understand why this is true. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote by $L=\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z_i\partial \bar{z_j}}\right)$ the Levi matrix of a smooth function $f$, by $H(f)$ its Hessian and by $X\in M_{2n,n}(\mathbb{C})$ the matrix
\begin{equation*}
X=\begin{pmatrix}
Id\\
iId
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation*}
We then have
\begin{equation*}
L=\overline{X}^tH(f)X
\end{equation*}
It follows that if $v\in\mathbb{C}^n$ verifies $\bar{v}^tLv = \lambda |v|^2$ for $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ then
\begin{eqnarray*}
\overline{(Xv)}^tH(f)(Xv) &=& \bar{v}^tLv \\
                          &=& \lambda |v|^2\\
                          &=& \dfrac{\lambda}{2}|Xv|^2
\end{eqnarray*}
We deduce that if $L$ is negative (positive) then $H(f)$ has $n$ negative (positive) eigenvalues.